# ValueError (could not broadcast) when using word vectors: how to fix?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, spacy, valueerror

I am trying to make a chatbot for a project, and I'm using spaCy. I'm following a tutorial, and I need to create a 2D array, X, with as many rows as there are sentences in my dataset. Each row is meant to be a word vector describing the sentence. However, when I try to make this array I get an error. I am not quite sure what causes this as I am new to spaCy and NLP in general.

I have tried to find out out what the problem is from the documentation. I have also looked at Stack Overflow but couldn't find anything that explained my problem.

```
import spacy
import numpy
#load spacy nlp model
nlp = spacy.load("en_core_web_sm")

#calculate the length of my sentences dataset
n_sentences = len(sentences)
#calculate the dimensionality of nlp model
embedding_dim = nlp.vocab.vectors_length
#X is a 2D array with as many rows as there are sentences in my dataset
#Each row is a vector describing the sentence
#initialise array with zeros
X = numpy.zeros((n_sentences, embedding_dim))
#iterate over sentences
for idx, sentence in enumerate(sentences):
   #pass each sentence to nlp object to create document
   doc = nlp(sentence)
   print(doc.vector.shape)
   #save document's .vector attribute to corresponding row in X
   X[idx, :] = doc.vector
```

It is the final line that throws the error, as far as I can tell.

```
ValueError: could not broadcast input array from shape (96) into shape (1,0)
```

I don't know what is causing this as I am not very familiar with numpy arrays and array shapes. My dataset, sentences, is a simple list of strings. I was expecting to end up with a 2D array containing word vectors. The tutorial I am following says the code is correct so I am not sure why it is not working for me, I think I must have missed something.

This is for an academic (A-Level) project.

Comment: Thanks @halfer, I'm new to the site and hadn't known it was disapproved of. I can see now that it might have sounded desperate and not very polite. I won't do that in future.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `en_core_web_sm` model doesn't include word vectors. You can download the `en_core_web_md` or `en_core_web_lg models` instead, which do.

[Reference](https://github.com/explosion/spaCy/issues/1651)

```
nlp = spacy.load("en_core_web_md")
print (nlp.vocab.vectors_length)
```

Output:

```
300
```